# Deploying an App Engine app using OAuth2 hangs forever

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I'm using the latest App Engine SDK on Windows 8.1 and trying to deploy a python app using the following command line:

```
appcfg.py update --oauth2 app.yaml
```

The browser opens and I'm asked to choose a Google account, than to accept App Engine's permissions.

Then, instead of updating the app, the choosing and accepting process repeats itself, but after accepting, both the browser tab and appcfg.py hang forever.

Am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Solved by installing the latest [Google Cloud Sdk](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/), and authenticating it using

```
gcloud auth login
```